# Webscraping on BeautifulSoup and Git Bash and transferring to a CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, scrapy

So I have been Webscraping on a website with a table, which I want to ideally webscrape into a excel sheet and keep it into a table, I will input what I have, I have used scrapy and BeautifulSoup and I have problem with both. Help would be great!

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('tbody', {"id":"category_content"})

print(name.text)
~
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use Selenium or Scrapy with Splash,my recommendation for small tasks is Selenium, you can learn basics in a day.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#install chrome if none and download chromedriver and add path to it
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/Python/chromedriver", options=options)
driver.get("https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/")
time.sleep(2)
soup = bs(driver.page_source,'lxml')
name = soup.find('tbody', {"id":"category_content"})
for i in name:
        print(i.find('a').text)
```